# Graph with constant edge connectivity that remains connected after edge removals

Tags: graphs, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, randomized-algorithms, connected-components

I have an undirected graph $(V, E)$ with constast edge connectivity $\lambda$. Each edge is sampled independently with probability $min\{1,\frac{c \ln n}{\lambda}\}$ for some $c > 0$. I need to prove that I can pick smallest sufficiently large $c$ so that the graph $(V, E')$, constructed from the sampled edges is connected.

My attempt: A simple observation I made is that $(V, E')$ is connected if there is an edge across all cuts. Then, the probability that for a cut of a given size $k$ in the original graph, at least one edge is sampled in $E'$ is $min\{k,k\frac{c \ln n}{\lambda}\}$ from linearity of expectation (since edges are drawn independently).

I do not know what else I can observe from here.

Comment: What is $n$? Is it the number of vertices?

Comment: Also, whats stopping you from choosing $c>\lambda$ and making the probability for each edge to be chosen into $1$ (which will guarantee $E'=E$)?

Comment: As stated your question does not make sense; as @nirshahar pointed out, nothing prevents you from taking a value of $c$ that makes $c \ln n / \lambda \geq 1$. If you want to find a minimum $c$ that guarantees connectedness (with high probability), then the question gets more interesting, but you should clarify this.

Comment: Edited now, specifying that